# continuous subgroups with ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I would like to summarize my experimental data every time a condition changes.

For example:

```
> df=data.frame(tos=1:9, temp=rep(c(25,50,25), each=3), response=c(3.2,3.3,3.3, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 3.5,3.6,3.5))
> df
    time temp response
1   1   25      3.2
2   2   25      3.3
3   3   25      3.3
4   4   50      6.5
5   5   50      6.5
6   6   50      6.5
7   7   25      3.5
8   8   25      3.6
9   9   25      3.5
```

I would like to summarize this in this way:

```
temp response.mean
25      3.3
50      6.5
25      3.5
```

If use ddply like this:

> library(plyr)
>   ddply(df, c("temp"), summarize, reponse.mean=mean(response)

the output is:

```
  temp response.mean
1   25           3.4
2   50           6.5
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one way to accomplish this

```
# find how many observations in each experiment
tmp1    = rle(df$temp)$lengths

# create a column referring to experiment number
df$expt = rep(1:length(tmp1), tmp1)

# compute means for each combination of temp and expt
ddply(df, .(expt, temp), summarize, response.mean = mean(response))
```

This produces the output

```
   expt temp response.mean
1    1   25      3.266667
2    2   50      6.500000
3    3   25      3.533333
```

Comment: Flip `expt` and `temp` in your `ddply` call so the result is sorted in the correct order.  Other than that, awesome answer.

Comment: @joshua. thanks for the suggestion. i flipped `expt` and `temp` and updated the output

Comment: Can't get enough of `rle`. :)

Comment: I just started writing an answer with `rle` and then I saw your answer! =) `rle` comes to the rescue, again! Anyway, do you really need to use `ddply`? You can use `tapply` instead: `with(df, tapply(response, expt, mean))` to get means, and extract `$values` vector from `rle` object.

Comment: @aL3xa. yes, you can use `tapply`. i use `plyr` commands as i find them to be conceptually more elegant and easier to grasp.

Comment: I absolutely agree - I also use `plyr` because it's straightforward, but sometimes you don't want your code to depend on external packages. Damn, if only @hadley's packages were in base R... =)